# Compactness of the solution operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, compact-operators

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The bilinear form $$a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dx$$ is elliptic on $H^1(\Omega)/\mathbb{R}$. The correspoding problem $$a(u,v)=(f,v)$$ for all $v\in H^1(\Omega)/\mathbb{R}$ requires the compatibility condition $f\in\{g\in L^2(\Omega):\int_{\Omega}g=0\}$.
Is the solution operator $$G:\{g\in L^2(\Omega):\int_{\Omega}g=0\}\to H^1(\Omega)/\mathbb{R}\to\{g\in L^2(\Omega):\int_{\Omega}g=0\}$$ compact?

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: $\Omega$ is a smooth open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key question here is whether an embedding of the Sobolev space into the Lebesgue space $L^2(\Omega)$ be compact or not. Generally, for the embedding to be compact, it suffices to assume that domain $\Omega$ is bounded and satisfies a cone
condition (for details, see "Sobolev spaces" by R. Adams).

Comment: I know that for a sufficiently smooth domain the embedding from $H^1$ to $L^2$ is compact, but in this particular case where quotient spaces have been invoked, does it remain compact? I want this for the correspond eigenvalue problem.

Comment: Vivek: Write down a formal definition of the quotient norm in 
$H^1(\Omega)/{\mathbb{R}}$, namely,
$$\|u\|=\inf_{C\in\mathbb{R}}\|u-C\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\,\,,$$
and notice that its value $\|u\|$ is achieved 
on the orthogonal projecton of element $u$ on the subspace
$$ \widetilde{H}^1(\Omega)\overset{def}{=}\Bigl\{u\in H^1(\Omega)\colon 
\int\limits_{\Omega}u(x)\,dx=0\Bigr\}.$$
Construct the required orthogonal projector. Due to the Poincare 
inequality, the norm $\|u\|_{H^1}$  on subspace $\widetilde{H}^1$ 
is equivalent to the norm $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$. The rest you know.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly,
$$
(\nabla u,\nabla v)_{L^2(\Omega)}=(f,v)_{L^2(\Omega)}, \quad \text{for all $v$},
$$
and hence for $v=u$:
$$
c|u|^2_{H^1(\Omega)}\le|\nabla u|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}=(\nabla u,\nabla u)_{L^2(\Omega)}=(f,u)_{L^2(\Omega)}\le |f|_{L^2
}|u|_{L^2},
$$
which implies that $f\mapsto u$ is compact from $L^2$ to $H^s$, for all $s<2$.